# Executing Android commands through Python and storing the result in a list

Tags: android, python

I am executing ADB commands through Python and it works fine till some extent. 
The code is :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import string
import os
import subprocess

cmd = 'adb shell ls'
s = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split())
print "Again"
t = str(s)
for me in t.split('\n') :
    print "Something"
    print me[1]
```

The output i get is :

```
static-243:Scripts adityagupta$ ./hellome.py 
Again
Something
s
static-243:Scripts adityagupta$ config
cache
sdcard
acct
mnt
vendor
d
etc
ueventd.rc
ueventd.goldfish.rc
system
sys
sbin
proc
init.rc
init.goldfish.rc
init
default.prop
data
root
dev
```

Any suggestion i could make each a list and store each element in it. 
The list should look like

list = [cache, sdcard, acct, mnt, vendor ..] and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shouldn't you use the `check_output` convenience function?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

cmd = 'adb shell ls'
s = subprocess.check_output(cmd.split())
print s.split('\r\n')
```

It works just fine here (Ubuntu box). Note that the newline separators are '\r\n' instead of just '\n'.

Comment: Awesome. How can i forget check_output. Thanks. That is exactly what i was looking for.